# What is the difference between Ext.Components' isVisible() and isHidden() method?

Tags: extjs

In ExtJS document, https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.Component.html,
There is no clear description of both the methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this question you need to analyze the source code. Here is the method [isHidden](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/src/Component.js-1.html#Ext.Component-method-isHidden):

```
...
isHidden: function() {
    return this.hidden;
},
...
```

And here is the method [isVisible](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/src/Component.js-1.html#Ext.Component-method-isVisible)

```
...
isVisible: function(deep) {
    var me = this,
        hidden;

    if (me.hidden || !me.rendered || me.destroyed) {
        hidden = true;
    } else if (deep) {
        hidden = me.isHierarchicallyHidden();
    }

    return !hidden;
},
...
```

Besides `hidden`, `isVisible` checks whether this component is already rendered, and whether it is in the process of destruction.
Also when `isVisible` calling with parameter `deep`, it can check if the element is displayed, for example, in the collapsed panel